How do I change the color of the background of line numbers in visual studio code?
I've been messing around with the workbench.colorCustomizations options in my settings.json file in VScode. I've managed to make everything change to the intended color (visible here), except for the background of the line numbers, shown here.
My code for customizing these colors is:
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "[Catppuccin Mocha]": {
          "editor.background": "#181825",
          "editor.foreground": "#181825",
          "terminal.background": "#181825",
          "activityBar.background": "#181825",
          "statusBar.background": "#181825",
          "editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground": "#181825",
          "tab.inactiveBackground": "#181825",
          "tab.activeBackground": "#181825",
          "breadcrumb.background": "#181825"
        }
      },

I've tried several different options from the VScode wiki, notably: editorLineNumber.foreground, editorLineNumber.activeForeground, and editorLineNumber.dimmedForeground, but they all only change the color of the numbers themselves, not the background. I figured that editor.background or editor.foreground would do something, but alas, no luck.
Any clue what command I would use to change the color?

try editor.lineHighlightBackground

I think the closest you can get is:
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorGutter.background": "#6006",         // last digit is opacity
  // "editorGutter.background": "#ff000060",  // last 2 digits are opacity
}

That editorGutter also includes where the folding controls, breakpoint indicators, etc. live so to see them well you will need some opacity - especially for the folding controls.

Yes editorGutter.backgroud worked for me as well

For me this configurations work
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorGutter.background": "#181825"
}

Update:


That changes the color of the letters, not the color of the pane.
